# Using a Time Zone Conversion When Dynamically Generating Results

Tags: php

If I understand correctly, the code below converts `$row["datesubmitted"]` from one timezone to another.

I would like to print the converted `$row["datesubmitted"]` dynamically in an HTML table.  Is there a way that I can apply the conversion below for each row that is pulled from MySQL?  I assume that I can't just plug $row["dt"] into the code since there is no field called "dt" in the MySQL that I am using.

Thanks in advance,

John

```
$dt = new DateTime($row["datesubmitted"], $tzFrom); 
$dt->setTimezone($tzTo);
```

Comment: WebbieDave, why did you delete your response?  It helped me solve my problem.

Comment: Sorry. I was trying to find a more efficient way to do it. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your recordset creating new DateTime objects for each row:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $dt = new DateTime($row["datesubmitted"], $tzFrom); 
    $dt->setTimezone($tzTo);
    echo '<tr><td>'.$dt->format('Y-m-d H:i').'</td></tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With help from others, here is what I got to work:

```
$tzFrom = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'); 
$tzTo = new DateTimeZone('America/Phoenix'); 


$result = mysql_query($sqlStr);

$arr = array(); 
echo "<table class=\"samplesrec\">";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $dt = new DateTime($row["datesubmitted"], $tzFrom); 
    $dt->setTimezone($tzTo);
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="sitename1"><a href="http://www.'.$row["url"].'">'.$row["title"].'</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="sitename2name">Submitted by <a href="http://www...com/sandbox/members/index.php?profile='.$row["username"].'">'.$row["username"].'</a> on '.$dt->format('l, F j, Y &\nb\sp &\nb\sp g:i a &\nb\sp &\nb\sp  \A\Z &\nb\sp \T\i\m\e').'</td>';

    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="sitename2"><a href="http://www...com/sandbox/comments/index.php?submission='.$row["title"].'&submissionid='.$row["submissionid"].'&url='.$row["url"].'">'.$row["countComments"].' comments</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
echo "</table>";
```